# Is the composition of closed unbounded operators closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space with linear subspaces $U,V$. Then a (not necessarily bounded) linear operator $T:U\to V$ is said to be *closed* if $$\text{Graph}(T)\equiv\lbrace(u,Tu):u\in U\rbrace$$ is closed in $H\oplus H$.

Now let $U,V,W$ be linear subspaces of $H$ and $S:U\to V$, $T:V\to W$ be closed (not necessarily bounded) linear operators. Clearly $T\circ S:U\to W$ is a linear operator. We have that $\text{Graph}(S)=\lbrace(u,Su):u\in U\rbrace$ and $\text{Graph}(T)\equiv\lbrace(v,Tv):v\in V\rbrace$ are closed in $H\oplus H$ and need to show that $\text{Graph}(TS)\equiv\lbrace(u,TSu):u\in U\rbrace$ is closed in $H\oplus H$.

So if $(u_n,TSu_n)\in\text{Graph}(TS)$ with $(u_n,TSu_n)\to(x,y)\in H\oplus H$, then we need to show that $(x,y)\in\text{Graph}(TS)$ i.e. that $y=TSx$. We find that $u_n\to x$ and $TSu_n\to y$. Clearly $y=TSx$ if $S$ and $T$ are bounded, but I am looking at unbounded operators here. How can I use the fact that $S$ and $T$ are closed to prove that $TS$ is closed when $S$ and $T$ are unbounded/not continuous?

Comment: The linear subspaces are not necessarily closed, are they?

Comment: No. More generally, I'm trying to establish that given a complex Hilbert space $H$, the category $\mathcal{U}(H)$ whose objects are linear subspaces of $H$ and whose morphisms are closed linear operators between them is, in fact, a category.

Comment: That involves proving that the composition of two morphisms i.e. closed linear operators is also a closed linear operator.

Comment: I'm not sure it holds. I think we'd need $(Su_n,\,TSu_n)\to (Sx,y)$ for the next step in the proof.

Comment: But I've just read in a research paper that the category described above is a category. Do you agree that the composition of two closed linear operators must be closed for this to be a category (to satisfy the axiom for composite of two morphisms to be a morphism)?

Comment: Yes, that should mean that. I also wanted to construct a counterexample without success, so it might indeed hold..

Comment: The composition of two closed operators is not closed, in general. Please see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/442808/102946).

Answer (score -1):

First, note that $$X=\{(u,Su,TSu):u\in U\}\subseteq H^3$$ is both closed and convex.  Thus it is weakly closed, and (since $H$ is reflexive) any bounded subset of $X$ is weakly compact.

Second, let $\pi_{1,3}$ denote the projection $H\oplus H\oplus H\to H\oplus H$ that omits the middle direct summand.  Clearly, $\pi_{1,3}X=\mathrm{Graph}(TS)$.  Since continuous maps send (weak) compacta to compacta, any bounded subset of $\mathrm{Graph}(TS)$ is (weakly) compact.  In particular, any such set $Y$ is weakly (and so strongly) closed.

Finally, suppose $\{(u_n,TSu_n)\}_n\to(v,w)$.  Then $\{(u_n,TSu_n)\}_n$ is bounded; choose bounded compact $Y\supseteq\{(u_n,TSu_n):n\}$.  Since $Y$ is closed, $(v,w)\in Y\subseteq\mathrm{Graph}(TS)$.

Comment: There's an error in the argument in the middle paragraph: bounded subsets of images of continuous linear operators are not images if bounded sets, in general (even if the operator is surjective).